# function "add_submenu_page in wordpress connects to the home page instead of the submenu page

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, submenu

note: updated the code with suggested code

I am creating a menu and submenu in the wordpress admin for a plugin.
The menu item of the main menu works fine and goes to the right php file(page).
but the submenu shows the text of the menu but when clicked on it it redirects to the 404 page and in my case it will go to the homepage. I have spend some hours over the code and it looks like I am overseeing something. Here is the code:

```
class BbtbPlugin{

   public function __construct(){
      add_action( 'init', array( $this,'bbtb_admin_menu' ));
   }
   public function bbtb_admin_menu() {
     add_menu_page(
        'Bricks by the Bay conventions',
        'BBTB conventions',
        'manage_options',
        'bbtb_conventions',
        'all_bbtb_conventions',
        'dashicons-media-spreadsheet',
        11
      );
      add_submenu_page(
        'bbtb_conventions',
        'Settings',
        'Settings',
        'manage_options',
        'bbtb_settings',
         function () { // anonymous callback function
            include "includes/setting_page.php";
        }
       );
       function all_bbtb_conventions() {
        include "includes/add_convention.php";
       }
    }
  }
```

So I checked if the function of the submenu works by replacing in the add_menu_page the 'all_bbtb_convention' with 'bbtb_settings'. Then the function works.

So there must be something in the add_submenu_page settings I am missing

Answer (score 1):

Figured out I need to change the `add_action( 'init', array( $this,'bbtb_admin_menu' ));` replace the `init` with `admin_menu`.
Now it works good

Answer (score 0):

It may be because you are using the same name of the slug in the name of the callback function, try changing it.

You can also do the following:

```php
add_submenu_page(
    'bbtb_conventions',
    'Settings',
    'Settings',
    'manage_options',
    'bbtb_settings',
    'bbtb_settings_callback'
);

function bbtb_settings_callback() {
    include "includes/setting_page.php";
}
```

You can even omit the callback function with an anonymous one.

```php
add_submenu_page(
    'bbtb_conventions',
    'Settings',
    'Settings',
    'manage_options',
    'bbtb_settings',
    function () { // anonymous callback function
        include "includes/setting_page.php";
    }
);
```

There is also no need to add a conditional to verify the capacity of manage_options, because for something the capacity is set in parameter 3 in `add_menu_page()` and in parameter 4 in `add_submenu_page()`

I hope I have helped you, greetings!

Comment: Thank you for the info. I am new with all this. I tried both suggestions but the same problem occurs.

Comment: @joam777 What action hook are you using to create the menus?